# EF Core, 'generated' Column based on Navigation Reference

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, .net-7.0

I have a Model like so:

```
class Reception:

    public DateTime? Time{
         get {
             return _Time;
          } 
         set { 
              if (_Time != value) { 
                   _Time = value;
                   _timeliness = null;
              } 
          } 
    }

    private DateTime? _Time { get; set; } = null;
    
    
    public TimeSpan? Timeliness
        {
            get
            {
                if (!this._timeliness.HasValue)
                {
                    this._timeliness = CalculateTimeliness();
                }
                return this._timeliness;
            }
            set
            {
                this._timeliness = value;
            }
        }
   private TimeSpan? _timeliness { get; set; }
    
   private TimeSpan? CalculateTimeliness()
        {
            var timeliness = (this.Time.HasValue && this.FOREIGNTABLE != null) ? this.Time - this.FOREIGNTABLE .Time: null;
            if (timeliness > TimeSpan.Zero)
            {
                
                return timeliness;
            }
            return null;
        }
    //Foreign Keys:

   public Guid FOREIGNTABLEID{ get; set; }  


   public virtual foriegnClass FOREIGNTABLE{ get; set; }
```

The problem occurs when I create an instance of this model like so:

```
var newRecep = new reception{FOREIGNKeyId = <someId>,Time = <someDateTime>};
MyDbContext.MyReceptions.Add(newRecep);
MyDbContext.SaveChanges();
```

The problem is that, even though I assign a valid foreign key to foreignKeyId, `Timeliness` doesn't get inserted into my database. Debugging shows that this is because the navigation reference `ForeignTable` is null, even though i set the foreign key id. Any ideas as to how to make this work?

Comment: I fail to see how this foreignkey object is related to timeline. Also, since you set `Time`, you also call `_timeliness = null;`. Avoid property setters with side effects.

Comment: @GertArnold I state in the question that if foreignTable is not null, andTime is not null, then  Timeliness is calculated as :
this.Time - this.FOREIGNTABLE .Time

Comment: OK, I forgot to scroll. The problem is that setting `FOREIGNKeyId` doesn't automatically populate `FOREIGNTABLE`.

Comment: Yea :( Do you know of way to make force populate it?

Comment: The deeper problem is these troublesome properties. They cause highly unexpected behavior and database redundancy. In general, if an object's property is set, it's expected that afterward *that* property has the set value and nothing else was changed. Use simple get/set properties and add an unmapped get-only property that returns the calculated time difference. Then you can simply store the `Reception`, refetch it with `Include(r => r.FOREIGNTABLE)` and read the calculated value.